# Textbox's length property never return 0 with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wonder why the length property of a textbox never return 0 when I am getting it with JQuery. Even when the textbox is empty, `$(element).length` never return 0.

Lets say we have this code :

```
<input id="Text1" type="text" />

$(function () {            
    alert($('#Text1').length);
    var textBox1 = document.getElementById("Text1");
    alert(textBox1.value.length);

    $('#Text1').on('input', function() {
        alert($('#Text1').length);
        var textBox1 = document.getElementById("Text1");
        alert(textBox1.value.length);
    });
});
```

[JS Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/rponyvLu/)

Has you can see, the `$('#Text1').length` never return 0. With pure javascript, it return 0 when the textbox is empty.

Why ?

Comment: That's because `.length` in your code returns the length of the jQuery object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to get value of textbox using `.val()`. `$(element).length` will return the length of number of objects present in `$(element)`, which is 1 in your case:

```
 $(element).val().length
```

### Working Demo